# How can I easily make screenshots of screen regions on Arch Linux with i3 WM?

Tags: arch-linux, i3, screenshot

About a month ago I switched from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Arch and I'm quite happy with this decision. However, I miss some features with my new distro, especially <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>printscr</kbd> which in Unity allows selection of a screen region to be captured.

I use i3 WM. So, my question is: how can I configure Unity-like screenshot behaviour to be able to snap screen regions or windows with a keyboard shortcut or something (without digging into window id and console stuff)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's been a long time since I'd asked this question and it looks like it's helpful for some of the users. So I provide my own script for making screenshots with `xclip` and `imagemagick` packages.

First of all, install the above mentioned dependencies. Then you can do whatever you want with the script below. It supports making a screenshot of a whole screen or a screen region and also it automatically copies a screenshot to a clipboard so you can paste it everywhere (e.i browser or Telegram messenger).

A couple of not so hard to come up with hacks would add a support for capturing specific windows and toggle copying part.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# screenshots stuff
# TODO: docs

function help_and_exit {
    if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
        echo "${1}"
    fi
    cat <<-EOF
    Usage: scregcp [-h|-s] [<screenshots_base_folder>]

    Take screenshot of a whole screen or a specified region,
    save it to a specified folder (current folder is default)
    and copy it to a clipboard. 

       -h   - print help and exit
       -s   - take a screenshot of a screen region
EOF
    if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
}

if [ "${1}" == '-h'  ]; then
    help_and_exit
elif [ "${1:0:1}" == '-' ]; then
    if [ "${1}" != '-s' ]; then
        help_and_exit "error: unknown option ${1}"  
    fi
    base_folder="${2}"
else
    base_folder="${1}"
    params="-window root"
fi  

file_path=${base_folder}$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' )_screenshot.png
import ${params} ${file_path}
xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i < ${file_path}
```

And here is my reference shortcuts for an `i3wm` to make use of this script:

```
# take a screenshot of a screen region and copy it to a clipboard
bindsym --release Shift+Print exec "scregcp -s /home/ddnomad/pictures/screenshots/"

# take a screenshot of a whole window and copy it to a clipboard
bindsym --release Print exec "scregcp /home/ddnomad/pictures/screenshots/"
```

Comment: This works great & a great solution it is without any extra heavy tools it works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 47):

You can use `import`, part of ImageMagick.

**Capture a region**

This will change your cursor into a crosshair and when you click and drag to form a box, that box will be saved as `ss.png`.

```
import ss.png
```

**Capture whole display**

```
import -window root ss.png
```

You can also replace the word `root` with the window id to capture a specific window.

Comment: You can also click on a window after `import ss.png` in order to take a screenshot of that window.

Comment: This doesn't work from i3 config, however. Minimal example: add line `bindsym $mod+shift+s exec import ~/screenshot.png` to your config. Doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: See the other answer about flameshot. That's what I'm using these days.

Comment: @Chris_128 You have to use --release flag, ex `bindsym --release Print exec import ~/screenshot.png`. Check here for explanation as to why https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html

Comment: @LennyWhite, your suggestion did the trick, thanks a bunch! However, the `Print` part of your example statement was put there by accident, correct?

Comment: @Chris_128 Yeah sorry `Print` stands for printscr key. That's just the personal keybinding I use.

Answer (score 18):

[Flameshot](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot) is a decent alternative.

```
bindsym Print       exec flameshot full
bindsym Shift+Print exec flameshot gui
```

You can use option `-p /path/to/directory` to skip selecting the save directory.

You can edit config in here `~/.config/i3/config` and reload the config using `i3-msg reload`.

Comment: nice tool i was looking for such a tool to make some documentation. Even you can add marking to the screenshot

Answer (score 8):

have you tried [scrot](http://freecode.com/projects/scrot) a, simple commandline screen capture utility

ref., : https://faq.i3wm.org/question/202/what-do-you-guys-use-for-printscreen/

Comment: you can also use scrot -s to capture a specific region. run the command then click and hold then click on the second point, it'll create a file with date as filename in your current directory.

Answer (score 7):

First, install xclip, imagemagick and jq!

```
pacman -S imagemagick jq xclip
```

I have this line in my i3 config:

```
bindsym $mod+Print exec \
    import -window $( \
        i3-msg -t get_tree | \
        jq 'recurse(.nodes[]) | select(.focused).window' \
    ) png:- | \
    xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

This will put a screenshot of the active window on your clipboard when you press mod (Window / Alt) + Printscreen.

i3-msg -t get-tree gets all windows from i3 as json, then we use jq to get the window id of the focussed window. We pass it to imagemagicks import command and pipe the result to xclip who will put it on the clipboard!

Answer (score 3):

Use [maim](https://github.com/naelstrof/maim). It's more actively developed and depends on [slop](https://github.com/naelstrof/slop%20slop) which is way better.

Don't use scrot. 
Its selection box corrupts and leaves an impression in the screenshot (also the box deforms when resizing) when used over an updating window (say htop).

Comment: (1) What is “slop”? (2) What, exactly, is it better than? (3) Why?

Comment: 1. Select operation, used to select window regions [https://github.com/naelstrof/slop] 2. It's better than scrot because it doesn't undergo selection box corruption (Try scrot over htop). 3. idk.

Answer (score 2):

I like [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) for its post-processing capabilities (hand-drawn red circles!) and comprehensive configuration options.

You can grab a screen region by running

```
shutter --select
```

You can set up key bindings in `.config/i3/config` like so:

```
bindsym Print         exec shutter --full
bindsym Shift+Print   exec shutter --select
```

It takes a second to load, so you may want to autostart it in the background:

```
exec shutter --min_at_startup
```

Shutter will be accessible via a tray icon then, which gives you many useful options beyond the above.

Comment: Shutter can't easily be installed fully on Ubuntu 18.04 at this point in time (edit tool depends on unavailable library; custom PPA not up to date). Sad.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly edited the solution by [@ddnomad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/136629/ddnomad) above, here's the `bash` version of the script with more explicity and another flag that allows saving only to clipboard.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash -

help_and_exit() {
  cat <<-EOF
  Usage: scregcp [-h|-s|-c] [<screenshots_base_folder>]

  Take screenshot of a whole screen or a specified region,
  save it to a specified folder (current folder is default)
  and copy it to a clipboard.

    -h   - print help and exit
    -s   - take a screenshot of a screen region
    -c   - save only to clipboard
EOF
    exit 0
}

base_folder="./"
savefile=true
region=false
params="-window root"
while test $# -gt 0; do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help*)
      help_and_exit
      ;;
    -r|--region*)
      params=""
      shift
      ;;
    -c|--clipboard-only*)
      savefile=false
      shift
      ;;
    *)
      if [[ $1 =~ ^\- ]] ; then
        echo "error: unknown flag '$1'"
        help_and_exit
      fi
      base_folder="${1}"
      shift
      ;;
  esac
done

file_path=${base_folder}$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' )_screenshot.png
import ${params} ${file_path}
xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i < ${file_path}

if [ "$savefile" = false ] ; then
  rm ${file_path}
fi
```

Then this is what you add to `i3` `config`:

```bsh
bindsym --release Shift+Print exec --no-startup-id "/dir/to/script.sh -r $HOME/Pictures/screenshots/"                                   
bindsym --release Control+Shift+Print exec --no-startup-id "/dir/to/script.sh -r -c $HOME/Pictures/screenshots/"                        
bindsym --release Print exec --no-startup-id "/dir/to/script.sh $HOME/Pictures/screenshots/"                                            
bindsym --release Control+Print exec --no-startup-id "/dir/to/script.sh -c $HOME/Pictures/screenshots/"
```

So the keybinding is:

- `PrtSc` = make a screenshot
- `+Control` = only save to clipboard
- `+Shift` = only capture a specific region of the screen

Answer (score 1):

A very simple option if you have it installed or don't mind installing it is using **xfce4-screenshooter** and i3 config would be:

```
bindsym Print exec --no-startup-id xfce4-screenshooter
```

Caveat: although fairly lightweight there are some dependencies if you are not using any other xfce4 programs

Answer (score 1):

This perl6 script takes ***root, area, window,*** or ***delay*** ScreenShots using import and saves them in a $file and in the clipboard.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

sub print_window(Str $file) {
  qx{xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"} ~~ /(0x\S*)/;
  run <import -window>, $0, $file;
}

sub MAIN( Str $option where $option ∈ <root area window delay> ) {
  my $today = DateTime.now( 
    formatter => { 
      sprintf "%04d_%02d_%02d_%02d-%02d-%02d", .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second 
    } 
  );
  my $file  = "$*HOME/Dades/Imatges/ScreenShots/$today.png";

  given $option {
    when 'root'   { run <import -window root>, $file }
    when 'area'   { run 'import', $file              }
    when 'window' { print_window($file)              }
    when 'delay'  { sleep 10; print_window($file)    }
  }
  run <xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i>, $file;
  run <xmessage -nearmouse -timeout 3>, "Screenshot in clipboard, and saved in $today.png";
}
```

These are the key bindings in i3 to run the script:

```
bindsym $mod+Print exec Print_Screen root 
bindsym --release $mod+Shift+Print exec Print_Screen area
bindsym $mod+Mod1+Print exec Print_Screen delay
bindsym $mod+Control+Print exec Print_Screen window
```

Answer (score 1):

| Feature | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Full Screen | <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> |
| Selection | <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> |
| Active Window | <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> |
| Clipboard Full Screen | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> |
| Clipboard Selection | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> |
| Clipboard Active Window | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> |

### Requirements

- `maim`
- `xclip`
- `xdotool`

### Set-up

Set this on your i3 config file `~/.i3/config`.

```
## Screenshots
bindsym Print exec --no-startup-id maim "/home/$USER/Pictures/$(date)"
bindsym $mod+Print exec --no-startup-id maim --window $(xdotool getactivewindow) "/home/$USER/Pictures/$(date)"
bindsym Shift+Print exec --no-startup-id maim --select "/home/$USER/Pictures/$(date)"

## Clipboard Screenshots
bindsym Ctrl+Print exec --no-startup-id maim | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
bindsym Ctrl+$mod+Print exec --no-startup-id maim --window $(xdotool getactivewindow) | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
bindsym Ctrl+Shift+Print exec --no-startup-id maim --select | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

---

source: https://dev.to/dianjuar/i3wm-screenshot-shortcuts-3n7b