# How to have screenshots send to the clipboard by default?

Tags: clipboard, screenshot

I'm using Kali Linux in a Virtual Machine and have to dump a great number of screenshots of the terminal to a document in another container.

`ALT + PRINTSCR` takes a screenshot just fine but it writes it out into a folder on the workstation. It would be significantly faster for me if this went directly to the clipboard so I could navigate to the following machine and paste it into the document. I've looked around but I can't find a way to update my settings to make `ALT + PRINTSCR` default to writing to the clipboard, can it be done?

Comment: I made a script that does this for me. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346800/136629

Comment: What kind of document? It would be relatively simple to use LaTeX to generate a pdf (with an index, table of contents and whatever else you want) and automatically insert all the images in your directory. Would that be a valid option?

Comment: @terdon the document itself is being built outside the virtual machine where I'm taking the spreadshots. If I send them to the clipboard I can paste them directly into the document as needed. It would also prove useful (being on the clipboard) for Slack also.